# Associate folder with my application?

Tags: windows

How to associate a specific folder(not files with extension) with my application in windows, so that when i double click on that folder it open my application?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there's no application starting when you doubleclick on a folder, because you cannot "start" it with "open with" either. But as a workaround you could create a shortcut to your application under `[systemdrive]\user\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` and start your application over the rightclick->"send to" menu.